# Python .replace 'st' with 'street' but leave street name the same

Tags: python, replace, split, street-address

I'm trying to change st. to street, ave. to avenue, etc. using .replace() for addresses in a single cell. For example: WEST ST. should be WEST STREET or MOUNT PEBBLE RD. should be MOUNT PEBBLE ROAD

Here is my code:

```
if 'STREET' not in address and address.find('ST.'):
    address = address.replace('ST','STREET')
```

The result gives me WESTREET STREET. How can I leave the address name untouched without altering the address name? I tried .split() but most cells had different list lengths so it got really confusing.

Comment: Can st. appear at the begin of the string?

Comment: Is there any . in the string that is not part of an abbrev.? For example "West."?

Comment: Add single space before ST and STREET in replace address = address.replace(' ST',' STREET')

Comment: The reason why your code wasn't running was because there needs to be a period after ST in your `.replace()` code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if 'STREET' not in address and address.find('ST.'):
    address = address.replace(' ST.',' STREET')
```

Comment: I have added `.` with `ST`. You can use both as per your need.

Comment: @muffint0p you can accept the answer if it helps :).

Answer (score 4):

Try using Regex with boundaries.

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = """WEST ST
       MOUNT PEBBLE RD"""

toReplace = {"ST": 'STREET', "RD": "ROAD", "ave": "avenue"}
for k,v in toReplace.items():
    s = re.sub(r"\b" + k + r"\b", v, s)
print(s)
```

**Output:**

```
WEST STREET
MOUNT PEBBLE ROAD
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, the less the code the better.

```
address = "WEST ST."

if address.find('ST.'):
    address = address.replace(' ST.',' STREET')

print(address)
```

Comment: You could also do this `address = address.replace(' ST',' STREET')`

Answer (score 2):

I edited your code like this:

```
address = "WEST ST."

if 'STREET' not in address and address.find('ST.'):
    address = address.replace('ST.','STREET')

print (address)
```

Here is the result:

> WEST STREET

**You have to replace "ST." not "ST"**